# Error: The project seems to require yarn but it's not installed

Tags: vue.js, yarnpkg, vuejs3, package.json

I have a Vue3 project and use yarn as a package manager. When I try to run `yarn serve`, it exits with the following error message:

[image: yarn error]

Yarn is installed globally, if i run `yarn --version` I get the following output: `1.22.11`

The project is compiled successfully.

Here is my package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "view",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet": "^0.6.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.3.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "postcss": "^8.3.6",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.7",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^5.0.0-beta.3",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^5.0.0-beta.3",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^5.0.0-beta.3",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.0-beta.3",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found better solution (but looks lika a hack) , just add to .env File :

> VUE_CLI_TEST=true

as we can see in env.js, it checks, if process.env.VUE_CLI_TEST equals true to check that yarn exists

Answer (score 2):

I happens some times.
Have you tried deleting the **node_modules/** folder and the **yarn.lock** file ?
After deleting them, try again to install the project :

```
yarn install
```

Most of the time it works, hope it does for you ;)

Comment: I've tried this several times, but unfortunately, it did not work for me

Comment: For me just deleting the yarn.lock file before running the serve script was enough.

Answer (score 1):

I found a GitHub [Issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3941) which is similar to the question.

> Fix
>
> it happen because in @vue/cli-shared-utils/lib/env.js ran the yarnpkg command and on > solus only is avalible the yarn command. Hard editing this file to ran yarn command > all works fine
>
> @vue/cli-shared-utils/lib/env.js:27
>
> execSync('yarn --version', { stdio: 'ignore' })
>
> with this change all works fine

This fix however, did not work for me. I hard edited the function in `@vue/cli-shared-utils/lib/env.js:19` which is responsible for the detection of yarn and just returned true:

```js
// env detection
exports.hasYarn = () => {
  return true;
  if (process.env.VUE_CLI_TEST) {
    return true
  }
  if (_hasYarn != null) {
    return _hasYarn
  }
  try {
    execSync('yarn --version', { stdio: 'ignore' })
    return (_hasYarn = true)
  } catch (e) {
    return (_hasYarn = false)
  }
}
```

If anyone has a better solution, I will accept it.

Comment: Better be careful with this approach as modifying `node_modules` code could impact your workflow in the future where it should be left as it is. Try deleting yarn from your system and reinstall it again.

Answer (score 0):

To install **yarn** in your project, do this

> npm install --global yarn

after then, do this

> yarn install

Answer (score 0):

you should install yarn in your project
try this :

npm install --global yarn

the problem fixed i think

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if none of the above methods work,maybe since your Windows account name isn't English words,change it to a English name like 'C:\Users\abc' and fix up all relevant environment variables,especially in 'Path'，npm item.

---

PS:if you are a Chinese developer, look up my blog in here:[[Bug]  Vue 项目报错：The project seems to require yarn but it's not installed](https://juejin.cn/post/7135280238074232862)